# Ordenar Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>

Tags: java, json, classificação, map

Olá, dei uma pesquisada mas não consegui encontrar esse tipo de ordenação pelo ultimo valor desse Map.

Preciso ordenar um `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>` pelo ultimo valor Long, para retornar em JSON.

A estrutura está assim:

```
  "Map": {
            "Info A": {
                "SubInfo A": {
                    "X": 0,
                    "Y": 0,
                    "Z": 2,
                    "Total": 2
                }
            },
            "Info B": {
                "SubInfo B": {
                    "X": 2,
                    "Y": 2,
                    "Z": 4,
                    "Total": 8
                }
            }, 
            "Info C": {
                "SubInfo C": {
                    "X": 4,
                    "Y": 0,
                    "Z": 1,
                    "Total": 5
                }
            }
```

Ela deve ficar assim:

```
 "Map": {
            "Info B": {
                "SubInfo B": {
                    "X": 2,
                    "Y": 2,
                    "Z": 4,
                    "Total": 8
                }
            },
            "Info C": {
                "SubInfo C": {
                    "X": 4,
                    "Y": 0,
                    "Z": 1,
                    "Total": 5
                }
            }, 
            "Info A": {
                "SubInfo A": {
                    "X": 0,
                    "Y": 0,
                    "Z": 2,
                    "Total": 2
                }
            }
```

Com a Ordenação do "Total" decrescente.

Só encontrei ordenação simples. Ex: `Map<String, Long>`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia que possa me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Mapas de mapas de mapas começam a ser uma solução confusa pra manutenção do código. Você pode fazer com que seu 'value' que é um `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` seja na verdade uma Classe e, nessa classe, você teria como comparar esses valores usando um comparable Você ficaria com um `Map<String,SuaClasse>.` Sobre ordenação, lembre-se que Map é apenas uma interface que pode ser implementada de diversas formas. [Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817728/3271789) pode ajudar você.

Comment: Certo @Tobo, vou dar uma olhada nesse Post.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Tentei dessa vez com java.util.TreeMap, SortedMap mas infelizmente não deu certo. Com LinkedHashMap eu já havia tentado, sem sucesso no meu caso de Map de Map's. Estou verificando se posso aplicar a sua sugestão de criar uma Classe. Obrigado @Tobo

Comment: Cara você nao pode ordenar antes, criar uma lista ordenada antes e quando for jogar no maps vai está ordenado. Nesse caso ainda não e um map e sim uma lista.

Comment: Map<String, Map<String, Long>>result =
                items.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::String),
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::String)
                                 Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::Long));

Comment: Map<String, Map<String, Long>>result =
                items.stream() .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.long())).collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::String),
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::String)
                                 Collectors.groupingBy(Classe::Long));

Comment: `TreeMap` e `SortedMap` ordenam pelas chaves, mas no seu caso o `Long` é o valor (a chave é `String`). Já `LinkedHashMap` mantém a ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos e não vai servir. De qualquer forma, seria interessante [edit] a pergunta e colocar alguns exemplos do que pretende fazer. Vc só quer mostrar (imprimir na tela, salvar em arquivo, etc) os dados do map em alguma ordem específica? Ou quer que a estrutura sempre mantenha os elementos em ordem? Enfim, tb acho que a estrutura está complexa demais e era melhor revê-la mesmo, conforme já sugerido...

Comment: @EduardoRodrigues, infelizmente no meu caso não funciona criar uma lista e ordená-la antes de mapear. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Oi @hkotsubo, preciso ordenar esse Map para retornar em uma API RestFull. Os dados vem do Banco e sempre serão dinâmicos, é bem complexo mesmo, existe relação de 6 tabelas e alguns filtros aplicados no Java. Vou editar com exemplos. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Um detalhe é que um JSON Object (delimitado por `{ }`, como parece ser a resposta que vc quer) [não garante a ordem das chaves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214312), então mesmo que vc crie uma estrutura ordenada no Java, nada impede que a API de JSON gere o resultado em outra ordem (já que a ordem não importa, de acordo com a definição de um JSON). Talvez vc devesse rever a estrutura e retornar um array, por exemplo (algo como `[ { infoa }, {infob}, etc... ]`), pois aí a ordem é garantida

Comment: Então @hkotsubo como o JSON não garante a ordenação, na minha Response coloquei um 'LinkedHashMap<>()' que deve receber esse meu Map de forma ordenada, pois um Array no meu caso não soluciona o problema, infelizmente.

Comment: Mateus, dependendo da API que vc usar, ela pode não gerar o JSON na mesma ordem do `LinkedHashMap`. Testei com `org.json.JSONObject` ele muda a ordem (mesmo usando um `LinkedHashMap`), e o Gson do google mantém a ordem (mas não sei sei foi coincidência ou se ele respeita sempre a ordem). E de qualquer maneira, um JSON object, por definição, não garante a ordem (nem em maps a ordem deveria importar), então retornar um object no qual a ordem é importante já está errado. Se for possível corrigir algo, comece por aí...

Comment: @Mateus, escreva a **SOLUÇÃO** no campo de respostas e aceite-a como correta. Adicionalmente, não é preciso marcar a questão como "Resolvido".

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @neves. Abraço.

Comment: @hkotsubo Muito obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas, consegui encontrar uma forma de resolver meu problema. Como não encontrei uma forma de ordenar(pelo valor) meu Map de Maps um pouco complexo e também pelo fato que devo retornar um Map semelhante na *Response*, fiz o seguinte:

Criei uma VO contendo um Map de mesma complexidade e um Long que recebe meu Total contido no último Map de cada Map;

```
public class minhaVO {
    private Long total;
    private Map<String,Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> map;
}
```

Depois criei uma `LinkedList<>()` dessa VO `List<minhaVO> voListOrdenar = new LinkedList<>();` populei ela com todas as chaves e valores do meu Map e utilizando o `Collections.sort` ordenei de forma decrescente como precisava.

Dessa forma todos os itens da minha lista VO ficam ordenado pelo Total e consequentemente meu Map também.

Feito isso, criei um *For Loop* nessa Lista, incrementando um Map `LinkedMap<>()` idêntico ao da minha *Response*, porém de forma ordenada e finalmente passei ele para minha resposta que o JSON devolve.

Agradeço ao pessoal que sugeriu algumas dicas e tentou me ajudar.

Um abraço a todos da comunidade.